# how to combine several video random any one to create 1 new video? using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

how to combine several video random any one to create 1 new video?
for example, I have 10 videos: 01.mp4; 02.mp4 ... 10.mp4
I want to combine random 5 of them to create 1 video
example:
 (01.mp4+ 03.mp4+ 04.mp4+ 06.mp4 + 08.mp4) = 1 new video

### (02.mp4+ 04.mp4+ 05.mp4+ 06.mp4 + 09.mp4) = 1 new video

Similar: random combination of 50 videos of 1000 videos to create 1 new video?

Comment: Do they have the same properties, like resolution, codecs..etc?

Comment: Option 1: the same things, differing only in length.
Option 2: not the same things.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a text file with list of videos

```
file '02.mp4'
file '04.mp4'
file '05.mp4'
file '08.mp4'
```

If the files have the same properties, run

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy new.mp4
```

If not,

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -r 30 -vf scale=W:H,setsar=1 -ac 2 -ar 48k new.mp4
```